# Read data between last bracket

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller action in cakePHP sending data using a POST request in the following format;

```
address?level=node[Job][qs3]
```

What is the most elegant way in php or cakePHP to only return the value "qs3" from the GET request.

Currently when I output the value of $_GET['level'] I am returning "node[Job][qs3]". I would only like to return "qs3".

Comment: what is your output on using
pr($this->request->data); or debug($this->request->data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use the regular expression for this

```
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $_GET['level'], $matches);
echo $matches[1][1];
```

you can try like this

```
$level = explode("[",$_GET['level']);
echo trim(end($level), "]");
```

Comment: Clever, was hoping for a more elegant solution though. Shall wait a little longer before awarding you the answer though :)

Comment: I have updated my answer with regular expression you can check it now

Answer (score 0):

Probably :

`$_GET['level']['node']['Job']['qs3']`

or if Job is a variable here

`$_GET['level']['node'][$Job]['qs3']`

or replace $_GET by $_POST ( not being sure of having understood )

anyways a print_r($_REQUEST) shall help you on that one

Comment: Sorry Jack, not sure if I explain myself enough. I am trying to get "only" qs3 into a variable to use it in a lookup. I don't care about node or Job. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Sure a preg_match would do it then

`preg_match_all("~\[([^\]]*)\]~", $_GET['level'], $m);`

then end($m)[1] to retrieve last brackets contents

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty way of doing it, which has 0% elegancy, hence the infinite loop:

```
$text = "address?level=node[Job][qs3]";
$temp = $text;
while (true) {
    $begin = explode("[", $temp, 2);
    if (isset($begin[1])) {
        $end = explode("]", $begin[1], 2);
        $result = $end[0];
        $temp = $end[1];
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
echo $result;
```

PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8hz7-bstu

Comment: Thanks for the help Tibor B. So far the comment below is simple than this and currently working :)